# remove item from a list

Tags: c#, list

I have object `Card`

```
public class Card {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color CardColor { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

and I have list of `Card`. I want to remove `Card` from list that has different `ID` but other properties are same.

```
cardList.Remove(mycard);
```

is not working.

Comment: Are you sure `mycard` is in the list? Have you tried taking the indexOf of the mycard?

Comment: If `Card` has a different `ID` then is it really in the list?

Comment: Find the item in the list that matches, by comparing the Name, then remove that.

Comment: try overriding `Equals()` method where you can define how a `Card` is similar.

Comment: @Nicolai as I said there is a card in the list that has seme properties of `mycard` except `ID`

Comment: why will a card with different id and same properties be in list

Comment: Are you asking how to get `mycard` or you had already found `mycard' but have problems removing that ?

Comment: @Darshana if a property of the object is different, then it is not the same. My house is the same as the bungalow across the street, except I have another floor.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel The card is different. Implementing the `Equals` method would be a wrong concern for the class. I would suggest an `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the item in the list that matches, by comparing the Name (or whatever), then remove that.

For example:

```
var toRemove = cardList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == mycard.Name);
if (toRemove != null) cardList.Remove(toRemove);
```

Comment: `First()` will throw if none of the items in the list matches the predicate

Comment: Are you sure its `First`? maybe in this case a `SingleOrDefault` would be better to ensure you are removing a unique card.

if there are many cards with the same name then maybe should handle removing `IEnumerable<Card>`?

Comment: @JonEgerton well just to be clear and concise as to what that method is actually doing. As we do not know the full implementation of `Card` and its use. We cannot be sure that `Name` is really unique. Just saying...

Comment: I would not use `SingleOrDefault` but loop trough the results. Name is not an unique identifier, This way people with duplicate names will result in `null`.

Comment: @MauriceStam that was kind of my point. as I suggest at the end of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should override Equals method. Remove use Equals to evaluate if the card is the one that you want to remove.
So override it in Card class with the logic to evaluate if two cards are equals.

Comment: That assumes that the requirement is to do the remove that way every single time an item is removed, rather than just in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var card in cardList)
{
    var cardsMatching =     
        cardList.All(x=>x.Name==card.Name&&x.Color==card.Color&&x.Size==card.Size); 

    cardsMatching.Foreach(y=> {
         cardList.Remove(cardList.IndexOf(y));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may want to prevent cards with the same id to be inserted in the first place.

There are two simple approaches:

- Use a set with a comparer, such as:

  ```
  public class CardComparer : IEqualityComparer<Card>
  {
      public bool Equals(Card x, Card y) { return x.ID == y.ID; }
      public int GetHashCode(Card obj) { return obj.ID; }
  }

  var hash = new HashSet<Card>(new CardComparer());
  ```
- Use dictionary with ID as a key:

  ```
  var dict = new Dictionary<int, Card>();
  ```